# XML transformations in Scala

Tags: xml, scala, zipper

I am dealing with XML transformations right now. For example,

- replace all nodes `<a>` with `<b>`
- replace all nodes `<c x = "xxx">` with `<d y="xxx">` etc.

I am using standard `scala.xml` [RewriteRule](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.xml.transform.RewriteRule) and `RuleTransformer`. I extend `RewriteRule` and pass it to a `RuleTransformer` instance, which applies the rule to XML.

I know there are other tools for that job: `lenses`, `zippers`, etc. Can they transform XMLs as I need? What are their advantages in comparison to my current approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for a side note: the Scala XML scene is pretty sad. [Anti-XML](http://anti-xml.org/) was promising, but is now mostly abandoned ([Arktekk got it working on 2.10](https://github.com/arktekk/anti-xml/tree/scala-2.10), but I'm not sure how active that development is). Anti-XML did have [a really neat zipper implementation](http://anti-xml.org/zippers.html), though, that would allow you to write stuff like this:

```
import com.codecommit.antixml._

val myDoc = <foo><a/><c x="xxx"/><a bar="baz"><b/></a></foo>.convert

def replaceA(e: Elem) = (e \\ "a").map(_.copy(name = "AAA")).unselect

def replaceXxxC(e: Elem) = (e \\ "c").filter(
  _.attrs.get("x").exists(_ == "xxx")
).map(_ => <d y="xxx"/>.convert).unselect
```

And then:

```
scala> println(replaceA(myDoc))
<foo><AAA/><c x="xxx"/><AAA bar="baz"><b/></AAA></foo>

scala> println(replaceXxxC(myDoc))
<foo><a/><d y="xxx"/><a bar="baz"><b/></a></foo>
```

The basic idea is that you use selectors like `\\` to navigate into the XML, make "changes" locally with `map`, etc., and then back out of the zipper with `unselect`. This is the key benefit of using zippers (or lenses) for XML transformation—you get very imperative-like syntax for editing (it looks more or less just like navigation plus local changes) but also all the benefits of immutability.

[Scales XML](https://github.com/chris-twiner/scalesXml) also lets you do this kind of thing, but it's quite a bit more complex.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think the zipper (as a abstract concept not just the `anti-xml` implementation) is the right abstraction for the XML transformations I listed above ?

Comment: I don't know about "the right" abstraction. Lenses are similar to zippers in many ways and nicer in some, but I don't know of a good implementation for XML in Scala. I'd personally much rather work with zippers than the standard library's transformers, though.

Comment: Thanks. I will try zippers and compare them to the standard approach.